Supervisor not helping with PhD graduation requirement of publishing
I am in the final stages of my PhD thesis with a renowned university in South Africa. For me to graduate, I must publish at least two articles on my topic. I have raised  this with my supervisor and all he said  was "I will see which angle we can take". Since then I have reminded him twice about complying with that university requirement with no success.
I have sent him my drafts for further assistance but nothing has materialized. Can I go alone, trying to send my manuscripts to accredited journals and see what happens? If there is anyone whom I can co author with, better still.

Is this a requirement set down in some policy, or the rules and regulations of the University for the conferral of the degree? Or is it just a rule of thumb?

Over what period of time has this occurred?

What’s your major/research field

‘with a renowned university in South Africa .’ Nice! How does that figure into the situation, please. Calling AI-gen …

Have you raised this issue with a trusted third party?  Your department should have a PhD administrator who is skilled in dealing with these kinds of issues sensitively.  It is not in the interest of the supervisor to thwart your progression, so there should be ways within the school to unblock this situation.

Book a face-to-face meeting with your supervisor and openly discuss your concerns.
I will never suggest you submitting your draft to any journal without the permission from your supervisor. If you do, they can easily request to withdraw your submission or report for plagiarism.

That makes no sense. There's no risk in trying to publish alone other than less likely to be accepted. As for plagiarism, there is no risk unless they have plagiarised.

@Elk That's certainly not true; if you publish alone when you shouldn't have, that's a major breach.

Why would this be plagiarism?
